# MacBook Pro 2017 SSD write speed slow

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd, performance

I just bought a new MacBook Pro 2017 (no TouchBar) a month ago. I have run a speed test with Blackmagic Disk Speed Test application. The result is in image below.
[image: Blackmagic test result]

I think SSD write speed is a little slower than normal. Anyone can help me with this? Thanks so much.

Comment: Are you running the latest version of Disk Speed Test? Prior versions don't support the 2016/2017 MacBook Pros properly.

Comment: The *10 Bit YUV 4:2:2 2160* with 30 is really slow. Me on my bike (**no** pedelec) I have a 3 min average of ~37 (street, sunny day).

Comment: @grgarside I have downloaded newest version from Mac App Store. It's version is 3.1.

Comment: @klanomath So I wonder why? :(

Comment: Maybe MBP nTB and MBP TB are different in SSD Speed? Your MBP has also TDP limitation at 15 watts vs. 28 W on MBP with TouchBar, and has one fan vs. two in MBP with TouchBar.

Comment: If your drive is 85-90% full you'll start to see these kinda of write slowdowns. https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/does-macbook-slow-down-as-you-have-less-ssd-capacity.1700214/#post-18690080

Answer (score 2):

Im also getting very slow speeds with my MacBook Pro 2015 SSD. It is most likely something wrong with the app, in the past I got much faster with the same app on a older version with the same Mac.

Comment: Thank for your answer. If that is application issue, I will change to another benchmark app.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with my 2015 15" 1TB SSD. The Read speed is fine, above 1800MB/s, but the Write speed will go down to 600MB/s. Once I run Disk Utility and First Aid, the speed increases again.

Black Magic and Etrecheck report very different speeds, with Etrecheck showing much better performance than Black Magic.